# Issue with Custom view on Action Bar in android

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, custom-view

I am trying to set custom view on ActionBar in android, My code is given below:

```
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);

        LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) this
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View v = inflator.inflate(R.layout.custom_actionbar_layout, null);

        getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(v);
```

I want to show only custom view, here i attached screen shot of issue of overlapping.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use this code

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
// add the custom view to the action bar
actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar_view);
```

or can view detailed discussion [HERE](http://www.sanfoundry.com/java-android-program-add-custom-view-actionbar/)